# Convert subquery in Oracle to get better performance

Tags: oracle

I have below data from the view `XWDDSB143.v_getplans` *(for the particular `device_id` = 97440010917)*.

[image]

Data from another view `v_getDevices_detailed_report` *(for the particular `device_id` = 97440010917)* is as below

[image]

These views can be joined together using `device_id` column.

In the below query we are using subquery to fetch `amount` from the view `v_getPlans` based on a `device_id`. The view `v_getDevices_detailed_report` contains all the device_ids (not just 97440010917 as in the `where` clause).

```
SELECT
        d.device_id as msisdn, d.name, d.serviceTag,
        ( SELECT NVL( Sum( amount ), 0 ) FROM XWDDSB143.v_getplans p WHERE p.device_id = d.device_id ) as plans,0 as tax_amount,0 as total
    FROM XWDDSB143.v_getDevices_detailed_report d 
    where d.device_id='97440010917';
```

And the above query gives the result as below,

[image]

Can anyone help me rewrite the above query without using any subquery at all so that we get the same output. ***NO need to use any PL/SQL stuff , only pure SQL query.***

We are using *Oracle 19c.*

Comment: 1. Put your mouse cursor into the leftmost upper cell of result set. 2. Press Shift key. 3. Put your mouse cursor into the rightmost bottom cell. 4. Press Ctrl + C. 5. Select SO question input area and press Ctrl + V. This will be **much more** readable than images of text.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a join:

```
  SELECT d.device_id AS msisdn,
         d.name,
         d.servicetag,
         NVL (SUM (amount), 0) AS plans,
         0  AS tax_amount,
         0  AS total
    FROM xwddsb143.v_getdevices_detailed_report d
         LEFT JOIN xwddsb143.v_getplans p ON p.device_id = d.device_id
   WHERE d.device_id = '97440010917'
GROUP BY d.device_id, d.name, d.servicetag;
```

Comment: The OP's query is not an (`INNER`) `JOIN` it is the equivalent of a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

You could write it as a single `OUTER JOIN` and aggregate on the primary key for `XWDDSB143.v_getDevices_detailed_report` (and if you don't have a primary key then you could include the `ROWID` pseudo-column in the aggregation) and use `MAX` to get the other columns from that table:

```sql
SELECT d.device_id as msisdn,
       MAX(d.name) AS name,
       MAX(d.serviceTag) AS name,
       COALESCE(Sum(amount), 0) as plans,
       0 as tax_amount,
       0 as total
FROM   XWDDSB143.v_getDevices_detailed_report d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN XWDDSB143.v_getplans p
       ON p.device_id = d.device_id
WHERE  d.device_id='97440010917'
GROUP BY d.device_id, d.ROWID;
```

However sub-queries are not necessarily bad and it may be more performant to aggregate before joining using a sub-query:

```sql
SELECT d.device_id as msisdn,
       d.name AS name,
       d.serviceTag AS name,
       COALESCE(p.amount, 0) as plans,
       0 as tax_amount,
       0 as total
FROM   XWDDSB143.v_getDevices_detailed_report d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT device_id,
                SUM(amount) AS amount
         FROM   XWDDSB143.v_getplans
         GROUP BY device_id
       ) p
       ON p.device_id = d.device_id
WHERE  d.device_id='97440010917';
```

Comment: How does this query different from what @Littlefoot mentioned as his answer. Which one is better in terms of performance?

Comment: @to-find Littlefoot had a different answer initially and corrected it following my comment on their answer so we have ended up with similar queries. The difference is that mine ensures that the `XWDDSB143.v_getDevices_detailed_report` rows will not be aggregated together (but the `XWDDSB143.v_getplans` rows will be aggregated); Littlefoot's answer will aggregate `XWDDSB143.v_getDevices_detailed_report` rows together if they have the same `device_id`, `name` and `service_tag`. If those 3 are all guaranteed to be different then the queries all will output identically.

Comment: As for performance, my guess would be that my bottom query (aggregating before joining) is probably more efficient than my top query (aggregating after joining) and Littlefoot's query is about equal to my top query (since they are similar queries) - however, we don't have your tables, data, hardware, etc. so the best answer is for you to implement all the solutions and test them and see what works best for you.